# How can i divide my database into 7 rows each time

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

I have a data frame in which I have the Date and Days column and I want to divide my data frame into 7 days (week) and print one by one a week's date.
[image]

```
0   2017-01-01  Sunday
1   2017-01-02  Monday
2   2017-01-03  Tuesday
3   2017-01-04  Wednesday
4   2017-01-05  Thursday
5   2017-01-06  Friday
6   2017-01-07  Saturday
```

then next time print next 7 days

```
7   2017-01-08  Sunday
8   2017-01-09  Monday
9   2017-01-10  Tuesday
10  2017-01-11  Wednesday
11  2017-01-12  Thursday
12  2017-01-13  Friday
13  2017-01-14  Saturday
```

and so on.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are all the weeks complete? I mean do you always have Sunday to Saturday?

Comment: No. sometimes, the week will have not Sunday to Saturday, some days can be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values by `Sunday` with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for groups, for first group with `7` rows is necessary first row starting by `Sunday`:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(df['Day'].eq('Sunday').cumsum()):
    print (g)
```

If need list of DataFrames:

```
dfs = [g for for i, g in df.groupby(df['Day'].eq('Sunday').cumsum())]
```